# I need the length of an array element, and then print the last character

Tags: java, arrays

So, today, I was given a school project, and I really need help.

I need to find the first and last letter of each element in this array, and then print it. For all of you java people out there, could you please tell me what function, method, or bit of code I need in order to do this?

One of the issues that comes up when I compile and run it is that where it says charAt(a);, it tells me that it cannot take the character that is there, for whatever reason.

So, if you could help me work this out, I'll be grateful, as this is due tonight, and I just cannot figure it out.

Thanks much.

```
/**
 * Write a description of class Pokemon here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pokemon
{
public static void main (String [ ] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String array [ ] = new String [ 10 ];

    array [ 0 ] = "Charizard";
    array [ 1 ] = "Pikachu";
    array [ 2 ] = "Jigglypuff";
    array [ 3 ] = "Timburr";
    array [ 4 ] = "Conkeldurr";
    array [ 5 ] = "Gurdurr";


    System.out.println("------------------------========================------------------------");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("                 .\"-,.__");
    System.out.println("                 `.     `.  ,");
    System.out.println("            .--'  .._,'\"-' `.");
    System.out.println("             .    .'         `'");
    System.out.println("             `.   /          ,'");
    System.out.println("               `  '--.   ,-\"'");
    System.out.println("                `\"`   |  \\");
    System.out.println("                   -. \\, |");
    System.out.println("                    `--Y.'      ___.");
    System.out.println("                         \\     L._, \\");
    System.out.println("               _.,        `.   <  <\\                _");
    System.out.println("             ,' '           `, `.   | \\            ( `");
    System.out.println("          ../, `.            `  |    .\\`.           \\ \\_");
    System.out.println("         ,' ,..  .           _.,'    ||\\l            )  '\".");
    System.out.println("        , ,'   \\           ,'.-.`-._,'  |           .  _._`.");
    System.out.println("      ,' /      \\ \\        `' ' `--/   | \\          / /   ..\\");
    System.out.println("    .'  /        \\ .         |\\__ - _ ,'` `        / /     `.`.");
    System.out.println("    |  '          ..         `-...-\"  |  `-'      / /        . `.");
    System.out.println("    | /           |L__           |    |          / /          `. `.");
    System.out.println("   , /            .   .          |    |         / /             ` `");
    System.out.println("  / /          ,. ,`._ `-_       |    |  _   ,-' /               ` \\");
    System.out.println(" / .           \"`_/. `-_ \\_,.  ,'    +-' `-'  _,        ..,-.    \\`.");
    System.out.println("  '         .-f    ,'   `    '.       \\__.---'     _   .'   '     \\ \\");
    System.out.println("' /          `.'    l     .' /          \\..      ,_|/   `.  ,'`     L`");
    System.out.println("|'      _.-\"\"` `.    \\ _,'  `            \\ `.___`.'\"`-.  , |   |    | \\");
    System.out.println("||    ,'      `. `.   '       _,...._        `  |    `/ '  |   '     .|");
    System.out.println("||  ,'          `. ;.,.---' ,'       `.   `.. `-'  .-' /_ .'    ;_   ||");
    System.out.println("|| '              V      / /           `   | `   ,'   ,' '.    !  `. ||");
    System.out.println("||/            _,-------7 '              . |  `-'    l         /    `||");
    System.out.println(" |          ,' .-   ,' ||               | .-.        `.      .'     ||");
    System.out.println(" `'        ,'    `\".'    |               |    `.        '. -.'       `'");
    System.out.println("          /      ,'      |               |,'    \\-.._,.'/'");
    System.out.println("          .     /        .               .       \\    .''");
    System.out.println("        .`.    |         `.             /         :_,'.'");
    System.out.println("          \\ `...\\   _     ,'-.        .'         /_.-'");
    System.out.println("           `-.__ `,  `'   .  _.>----''.  _  __  /");
    System.out.println("                .'        /\"'          |  \"'   '_");
    System.out.println("               /_|.-'\\ ,\\\".             '.'`__'-( \\");
    System.out.println("                 / ,\\\"'\\\"\\,'               `/  `-.|\"");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("------------------------========Charizard========------------------------");

    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" ");        
    System.out.println("Items in array:  ");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("0 - " + array [ 0 ]);
    System.out.println("1 - " + array [ 1 ]);
    System.out.println("2 - " + array [ 2 ]);
    System.out.println("3 - " + array [ 3 ]);
    System.out.println("4 - " + array [ 4 ]);
    System.out.println("5 - " + array [ 5 ]);
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" ");

    int a = (array [ 0 ]).length();
    int b = (array [ 1 ]).length();
    int c = (array [ 2 ]).length();
    int d = (array [ 3 ]).length();
    int e = (array [ 4 ]).length();
    int f = (array [ 5 ]).length();


    char g = (array [ 0 ]).charAt(0);
    char h = (array [ 1 ]).charAt(0);
    char i = (array [ 2 ]).charAt(0);
    char j = (array [ 3 ]).charAt(0);
    char k = (array [ 4 ]).charAt(0);
    char l = (array [ 5 ]).charAt(0);

    char m = (array [ 0 ]).charAt(a);
    char n = (array [ 1 ]).charAt(b);
    char o = (array [ 2 ]).charAt(c);
    char p = (array [ 3 ]).charAt(d);
    char q = (array [ 4 ]).charAt(e);
    char r = (array [ 5 ]).charAt(f);

    System.out.println(array [ 0 ] + "  -  First letter of element: " + g + "    Second letter of element: " + m);
    System.out.println(array [ 1 ] + "  -  First letter of element: " + h + "    Second letter of element: " + n);
    System.out.println(array [ 2 ] + "  -  First letter of element: " + i + "    Second letter of element: " + o);
    System.out.println(array [ 3 ] + "  -  First letter of element: " + j + "    Second letter of element: " + p);
    System.out.println(array [ 4 ] + "  -  First letter of element: " + k + "    Second letter of element: " + q);
    System.out.println(array [ 5 ] + "  -  First letter of element: " + l + "    Second letter of element: " + r);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use,

```
    char m = (array [ 0 ]).charAt(a-1);
    char n = (array [ 1 ]).charAt(b-1);
    char o = (array [ 2 ]).charAt(c-1);
    char p = (array [ 3 ]).charAt(d-1);
    char q = (array [ 4 ]).charAt(e-1);
    char r = (array [ 5 ]).charAt(f-1);
```

becuse indexing starts with 0 and last letter's index is (length-1)

But it is better to use a for loop for this

```
for(int v=0;v<6;v++){
    System.out.println(array [ v ] + "  -  First letter of element: " + array[v].charAt(0) + "    Second letter of element: " + array[v].charAt(array[v].length()-1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot, and I can now finish my project. You're a lifesaver, my friend.

Comment: it's better if you can use a loop for program.

Answer (score 1):

Zero based indexing

```
char m = (array [ 0 ]).charAt(a-1);
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: @RohitGupta Ok, Is this not enough?

Answer (score 0):

This can help you:

```
for(String value: array)
{
    System.out.println(value.charAt(0) + " " + value.charAt(value.length() - 1));
}
```